# Check free inode percentage in java

Tags: java, unix, inode

I would like to check the free inode percentage through a java code in a unix file system. Is that possible? It seems that Java does not know anything about inodes, but is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

"inode" is a Unix concept, and not well-understood by the JVM. It would probably be easiest to implement this operation by using, e.g., `Runtime.exec()` to run the relevant system utility (e.g., `df -i`) and then parse the results. The output of utilities like this is generally easy to parse but, unfortunately, it isn't guaranteed to be consistent between platforms.

An alternative approach might be to implement a JNI module in C, that invokes the `statvfs()` function directly. This avoids the problem of parsing the output from a utility, but you've still got to find a way to build the module for any platform where it might be used.